# dynamically register receiver which on receive starts a service

Tags: android, dynamic, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-bluetooth

In my main activity I have a check box which when checked registers a receiver to listen out for changes to the bluetooth device i.e bluetooth connected to a device. 
when the phone becomes connected to a preselected bluetooth device, I want a service to be started from within the on receive once its called.
the problem is that when after clicking the check box "on" in the main activity, thus registering the receiver, if the user clicks the back button to exit the app, the app/android life cycle calls onDestroy, and i get an error saying leaked receiver. how can i register the receiver and keep it registered even if the user clicks the back button to exit the main activity.

the app only has one activity which is the main activity.
the receiver gets unregistered when the user un-checks the checkbox.

**addDrawerItems Method**

```
final IntentFilter blueToothFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    blueToothFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);

if (ctv.isChecked()) {
    if (!isblueToothRegistered) {
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, blueToothFilter);
        isblueToothRegistered = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} else {
    if (isblueToothRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        isblueToothRegistered = false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth OFF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**BroadCast Receiver**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    private Boolean bluetoothStart = false;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        //Toast.makeText(context, "Receieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String action = intent.getAction();

        final BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, CallDetectService.class);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


           if (device.getName().equals(mPairedBluetoothDevice)) {
               bluetoothStart = true;
               serviceIntent.putExtra("btConnected",bluetoothStart);
               startService(serviceIntent);

               showStatusBarIcon(true);

               detectEnabled = true;
               SharedPreferences sharedPreferences3 = getSharedPreferences("driveSafeMode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences3.edit();
               editor.putBoolean("mode", detectEnabled);
               editor.apply();
               toggleUI();


              // Toast.makeText(context, mPairedBluetoothDevice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)){
            stopService(serviceIntent);
            showStatusBarIcon(false);
            detectEnabled = false;

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences3 = getSharedPreferences("driveSafeMode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences3.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("mode", detectEnabled);
            editor.apply();

            toggleUI();

        }
    }
};
```

maybe when the user checks the check boxes a separate service gets started which
its only job is to register the receiver onStartCommand and the unRegisterReceiver onDestroy. the thing is though in that case the service could be running for days, listening for a bluetooth device to be connected. would that be ok though ?
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should register your `receiver` in your `manifest`. Use code only to enable / disable it.

Comment: so is possible to by checking the checkbox in the main activity, to register the receiver in the manifest, and then unchecking the box to unregister the receiver in the manifest? I thought that receiver registered in the manifest are always registered listening/on

Comment: Yes, these listeners are always registered. But they can be `disabled`.

Comment: ok sounds good! what im looking for is to give the user the choice, whether or not they want the app to start automatically if the phone is connected to bluetooth. by checking the box on or off.  do you get me?

Comment: Yes. Check this http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html

Comment: thanks very much! this "back button  on destroy" is quite annoying and makes things complicated. im not sure if i heard that its a android lifecycle issue. my code appears to work prefect if the user turns on the check box, then exits by pressing the home button or lock button, but doesnt work when they press the back button.

Comment: The activity will still leak the Broadcastreceiver if it is left regardless of the method used. The only difference is that it happens instantly when you press back. You should always unregister listeners registered in code.

Comment: thanks, so what im understanding is that i can declare/register the receiver in the manifest then enable & disable it using a checkbox in the main activity? if this is the case then thats exactly what i want. just another question if i use this approach is it possible to then have the Broadcast Receiver class as a inner class with the MainActivity Class? As I was having difficulties  passing variables/data from the MainActivity class to the BroadcastReceiver class.

Comment: It can be an inner class, but it would have to be static, so it wouldn't help much in this situation. However this is a different question. Please avoid mixing multiple questions.